# mySQL / PHP design pattern - one function multiple queries

Tags: design-patterns, php, mysql

So here's the gist of it. I'm looking for a design pattern where I can have one function, say `queryHandler` that gets the query and the parameters from a number of different functions and returns the said query results.

At the moment, I have a Core class which implements the singleton pattern for database object creation and so forth.

However, I want a design pattern that can handle different queries with different bind parameters. So, take these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = :bar

INSERT INTO foo (id, name, bar) VALUES (:id, :name, :bar)
```

Etc.

For the first one, I would have a `bindParam` where `:bar` would be PDO::PARAM_INT, however, in the second case it would be multiple `bindParams` with both INT and STR types.

I want my functions to just have one variable, and one call to the queryHandler:

```
$query = 'SOME QUERY HERE'
$this->queryHandler($query, $params ... or something)
```

Obviously, `queryHandler` would sort out how many params, their type, and do the query itself.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That smells like an SRP violation. Perhaps you might be better looking at the [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern and [data access objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

Answer (score 1):

Use a multidimensional array like $key => $value, $key2 => $value2 and iterate?

```
$data = array( 'column_name' => 'value' );
querysorter ( 'tblname', $data );
function querysorter{
foreach($data)
//bindparam here
}
```

Hope this helps, just had to do something similair.

Comment: how would you sort between the difference type of params? ie INT vs STR?

Comment: PHP does that for you, could you give me an example?

Comment: @RobertPounder No, PHP does not do that for you. Have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php PHP requires you to provide a format constant which denotes in which format the parameter should be transfered. If omitted, it will transfer it as a string. This does work in most cases, but not when it would result in an ambiguous type cast (e.g. because MySQL would accept both a string as well as an integer as first parameter to a certain function).